# googleTagManager using JQueryMobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I was working with an application using jQueryMobile and using googleTagManager instead of simple code for GA. Reviewing tracking of the website I found more visits for each page called. I mean, every time I see a simple page, is tracking for 2 or 4 visits. Here is the code:

```js
var dataLayer = dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push({'b_gaCode': 'UA-32085XX-3'});
dataLayer.push({'gaCode': 'UA-32085XX-3'});

var googleTagManager = function(w,d,s,l,i){
    w[l]=w[l]||[];
    w[l].push({'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});
    var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], j=d.createElement(s), dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';
    j.async=true;j.src='//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
}

$(document).on("pageinit",  function(event, ui) {
    googleTagManager(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-MX6TXX');
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple "Pageview" Tags set up in Google Tag Manager, firing for each page?

You could put your Tag Manager Container in *Debug Mode* then navigate to your web application, and check the Tags fired when the page has loaded.